# how to compare two timestamps in PHP?

Tags: php

In my code I've a scenario like this :

```
<?php
     $start = "03:00:00:am";
     $end   = "08:00:00:pm";

      if($start > $end) {}   
?>
```

I tried with unix timestamp but it didnt worked.

Comment: Learn from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Answer (score 5):

Try this, I do not think that the am, pm at the end is the correct formatting but with dates you should be able to test them in this way:

```
$start = strtotime("03:00:00");
$end   = strtotime("20:00:00");

if($start > $end) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<?php
$start = strtotime("03:00:00");
$end   = strtotime("20:00:00");

if($start > $end) {
 echo "Yes";
}
else{
    echo "No";
}
?>
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php